# How to change background-color of selected option in IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The below code gives background color of selected option as green (#7FFF00) in IE8 and IE9 but as black in IE11. So, how can i get the same background color in IE11 also. Is it possible to do so using CSS ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.car-select option[selected] {
    background-color: #7FFF00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="form_action.asp">
<select name="cars" class="car-select" multiple disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option selected value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is working correctly in IE11 and Firefox (the two I checked).  Note that the selected value is different from the element that currently has the focus in the browser.  If you click on a non-selected option, which changes the focus, you do indeed see the green background. (Remember to take out the disabled attribute first, or else you can't change the focus by clicking on the options.)

Comment: @MarcAudet: Yes it works after removing disabled attribute...but i want it to display it with green background for disabled field. It works as expected in IE8 and IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default user stylesheets overwrite everything you do with CSS when the select tag is disabled. This only seems to happen with more recent versions of IE/Firefox/Chrome etc.

So unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, it is not possible with CSS. I even tried using javascript to overwrite the stylesheet but that just gets overwritten too. It's very strange.

What are you trying to accomplish/ what is this for? Maybe we could help find an alternative way of doing what you need? (Add to your question instead of commenting)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the background Colour can be changed in Internet Explorer 11.

Settings --> Internet Options --> (Look at bottom) Appearance --> Colours. Deselect "Use Windows Colours" and choose the background Colour.
Click "OK"

Select Internet Options --> (Look at bottom) "Accessibility", select "Ignore colours specified on Webpages". That's all.